# Cannot Access Properties in Callback Function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, react-redux

I am using a library called [Papa Parse](http://papaparse.com/docs#config)  to parse a csv file to json. The parser is working fine, but I cannot call my action creator in the callback function that is specified in the 'complete' section of the config object for Papa parse. I believe this is a scope issue, but I have been unable to resolve it. The main part of interest below is why I cannot call either of the functions in the 'printFile' function, most importantly the 'addRoster' function. Please let me know you have any suggestions or ideas. Thanks!

Edit: Ignore that this is in snippet form. What is here is not runnable, I just couldn't get formatting to work.

```
class Roster extends Component {

  super(props) {

    this.printFile = this.printFile.bind(this);

    this.testMethod = this.testMethod.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.addRoster('test')
  }

  printFile(results, file) {
    this.props.addRoster(file);
    this.props.testMethod;
  }

  testMethod(test) {
    console.log("Winner")
  }

  fileDrop(file) {

    var config = {
      delimiter: "", // auto-detect
      newline: "", // auto-detect
      quoteChar: '"',
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: false,
      preview: 0,
      encoding: "",
      worker: false,
      comments: false,
      step: undefined,
      complete: this.printFile,
      error: undefined,
      download: false,
      skipEmptyLines: false,
      chunk: undefined,
      fastMode: undefined,
      beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
      withCredentials: undefined
    }
    Papa.parse(file, config)
  }


  render() {
    const {
      addRoster
    } = this.props;

    return ( <
      Grid >
      <
      Row >
      <
      MyDropzone onFileDrop = {
        this.fileDrop.bind(this)
      }
      /> < /
      Row > <
      /Grid>
    )
  }

}

export default connect(null, {
  addRoster
})(Roster);
```

Comment: Run the code snippet, there's an error `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",`

Comment: Sorry the snippet isn't supposed to be runnable. I just used that because I couldn't get the bracket formatting to work. @ppz

Comment: could you console.log(this) inside the `printFile` function just to know the scope. I assume, this callback is called with the a predefined context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you haven't added a constructor so the function was not binded? Try changing this

```
super(props) 
{
  this.printFile = this.printFile.bind(this);
  this.testMethod = this.testMethod.bind(this);
}
```

to

```
constructor(props) 
{
  super(props);
  this.printFile = this.printFile.bind(this);
  this.testMethod = this.testMethod.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Wow, careless error on my part. This fixed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi if that answer helped please upvote and accept the answer. This small incentive will help people like me to answer more queries , thank you

Comment: Hey, sorry. Pretty new to the system. Thanks for the help!